# Como passar via POST informações Javascript para o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

Tenho um `select` que é montado via consulta banco de dados.

```
<?php
      $tl_rel = "";
      $arg = array("select"=>"*","tabela"=>"TAB_RELATORIOS","where"=>"where login='{$_SESSION['login']}'");
      $obj_rel = $obj_pdo->getConsulta($arg);
      $tl_rel = count($obj_rel);
?>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label" for="opcoes">Relatórios Salvos</label>
        <select class="custom-select" id="opcoes" name="opcoes" onclick="mostra(this);">
          <option value="0" selected>Selectione</option>
<?php
            for($i=0; $i < $tl_rel; $i++){
                print "<option value='{$obj_rel[$i]->TABELAS}'>{$obj_rel[$i]->NOME}</option>";
            }
?>
```

Eu preciso pegar o texto do `option` selecionado pelo usuário para montar um segundo `select`, também via banco de dados.

Tentei fazer isso via Ajax através do código abaixo, porém o mesmo exibi o HTML todo no console.

```
function mostra(lista){
    var x = lista.options[lista.options.selectedIndex];
    var nome = x.text;
    if(lista.value != "0"){
        $("#Lista2").prop("hidden", true);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'relatorios.php',
            cache: false,
            data: { 'tabela': nome },
            success: function(retorno){
                alert(retorno);
            }
        });
    }else{
        $("#Lista2").prop("hidden", false);
    }
}
```

Há uma forma de fazer isso, sem que eu precise exibir todo o HTML como resposta?

---

Este é todo o código.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<title>Relatório de Follow Up Honda</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="relatorio" content="relatorio_prof_honda">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../imagens/logo-pequeno.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    body { background-image: url("../imagens/fundo.png"); }
    * { box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 10pt; }
    .corpo { width: 45%; height: 320px; margin: 150px auto auto 100px; padding: 5px; }
    .dropdown-item:hover{ color:#fff; text-decoration:none; background-color:#28a745; border-color:#28a745 }
    li { width: 90px; text-align: center; }
    li:hover { border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../java/jquery.selectlistactions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8)">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="novo.php">Novo</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="protocolo.php">Protocolo</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="relatorios.php">Relatórios</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<form action="" method="post" name="form" id="form" target="_blank">
  <div class="corpo">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <label for="dt_ini">De</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dt_ini" name="dt_ini" required autofocus />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for=""> </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <label for="dt_fim">Até</label>     
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dt_fim" name="dt_fim" value="<?php print date('Y-m-d'); ?>" required />
      </div>
    </div>

<?php
      $tl_rel = "";
      $arg = array("select"=>"*","tabela"=>"TAB_RELATORIOS","where"=>"where login='{$_SESSION['login']}'");
      $obj_rel = $obj_pdo->getConsultaDI($arg);
      //var_dump($obj_rel);
      $tl_rel = count($obj_rel);
?>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label" for="opcoes">Relatórios Salvos</label>
        <select class="custom-select" id="opcoes" name="opcoes" onclick="mostra(this);" onChange="DesmarcarOp();SelecaoRelatorio();">
          <option value="0" selected>Selectione</option>
<?php
            for($i=0; $i < $tl_rel; $i++){
                print "<option value='{$obj_rel[$i]->TABELAS}'>{$obj_rel[$i]->NOME}</option>";
            }
?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="novo_relatorio">Novo Relatório</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="novo_relatorio" name="novo_relatorio" maxlength="100" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for=""> </label>
        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="salvarrelatorio">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="salvarrelatorio">Salvar Relatório?</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="dipendentes" value="dipendentes">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="dipendentes">DI's Pendentes</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="registradas" value="registradas">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="registradas">DI's Registradas</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="entregues" value="entregues">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="entregues">DI's Entregues</label>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <label class="control-label" for="Lista1">Disponíveis</label>
        <select multiple class="custom-select" id="Lista1">
          <option value="idt_embarque">IDENTIFICACAO</option>
          <option value="invoice">NR INVOICE</option>
          <option value="nr_doc_carga_mast">NR MASTER</option>
          <option value="nr_doc_carga">NR HOUSE</option>
          <option value="dt_di">DATA D.I.</option>
          <option value="nr_di">NR D.I.</option>
          <option value="qtd_adicoes">NR ADICOES</option>
          <option value="historico">HISTORICO</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label class="control-label" for="btnAdd"> </label>
        <button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" style="width:25px;height:25px;margin:55px 0 0 25px">
          <svg style="margin:-10px 0 0 -6px" width="15" height="15" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="angle-double-right" class="svg-inline--fa fa-angle-double-right fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M224.3 273l-136 136c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.6-22.6c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9l96.4-96.4-96.4-96.4c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9L54.3 103c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l136 136c9.5 9.4 9.5 24.6.1 34zm192-34l-136-136c-9.4-9.4-24.6-9.4-33.9 0l-22.6 22.6c-9.4 9.4-9.4 24.6 0 33.9l96.4 96.4-96.4 96.4c-9.4 9.4-9.4 24.6 0 33.9l22.6 22.6c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l136-136c9.4-9.2 9.4-24.4 0-33.8z"></path></svg>
        </button>
      </div>
<script>

    function mostra(lista){
        var x = lista.options[lista.options.selectedIndex];
        var nome = x.text;
        if(lista.value != "0"){
            $("#Lista2").prop("hidden", true);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'relatorios.php',
                cache: false,
                data: { 'tabela': nome },
                success: function(retorno){
                    alert(retorno);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $("#Lista2").prop("hidden", false);
        }
    }

</script>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <label class="control-label" for="Lista2">Itens Rel.</label>
        <select multiple class="form-control" id="Lista2" name="Lista2[]">
          <option hidden selected value="cd_processo"></option>
          <option hidden selected value="dt_recebimento_doc"></option>
          <option value="idt_embarque">IDENTIFICACAO</option>
          <option value="invoice">NR INVOICE</option>
        </select>
      </div>
<?php
    //var_dump($_POST);
    @$tabela = $_POST['tabela'];
    $opcoes = "";
    $cabeca = "";
    $campo = array("/idt_embarque/i","/invoice/i","/nr_doc_carga_mast/i","/nr_doc_carga/i","/dt_di/i","/nr_di/i","/qtd_adicoes/i","/historico/i");
    $titulo = array("IDENTIFICACAO","NR INVOICE","NR MASTER","NR HOUSE","DATA D.I.","NR D.I.","NR ADICOES","HISTORICO");

    $arg = array("select"=>"*","tabela"=>"TAB_RELATORIOS","where"=>"where login='{$_SESSION['login']}' and nome='{$tabela}'");
    $obj_rel = $obj_pdo->getConsultaDI($arg);
    if(!empty($obj_rel)){
        $opcoes = explode("|",$obj_rel[0]->OPCOES);
        $tl_rel = count($opcoes)-1;
        print '<div class="form-group col-md-5">';
        print '<label class="control-label" for="Lista2">Itens Rel.</label>';
        print '<select multiple class="form-control" id="Lista2" name="Lista2[]">';
        for($i=0; $tl_rel > $i; $i++){ //inicio do for
            $cabeca = preg_replace($campo, $titulo, $opcoes[$i]);
            if($opcoes[$i] === "cd_processo"){
                print '<option hidden selected value="cd_processo"></option>';
            }elseif($opcoes[$i] === "dt_recebimento_doc"){
                print '<option hidden selected value="dt_recebimento_doc"></option>';
            }else{
                print '<option value="'.$opcoes[$i].'">'.$cabeca.'</option>';
            }
        }// fim do for
        print '</select>';
        print '</div>';
    }
?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" id="btnUp">
          <svg width="20px" height="20px" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="arrow-alt-circle-up" class="svg-inline--fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-up fa-w-16 text-success" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M8 256C8 119 119 8 256 8s248 111 248 248-111 248-248 248S8 393 8 256zm292 116V256h70.9c10.7 0 16.1-13 8.5-20.5L264.5 121.2c-4.7-4.7-12.2-4.7-16.9 0l-115 114.3c-7.6 7.6-2.2 20.5 8.5 20.5H212v116c0 6.6 5.4 12 12 12h64c6.6 0 12-5.4 12-12z"></path></svg>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" id="btnDown">
          <svg width="20px" height="20px" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="arrow-alt-circle-down" class="svg-inline--fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-down fa-w-16 text-success" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M504 256c0 137-111 248-248 248S8 393 8 256 119 8 256 8s248 111 248 248zM212 140v116h-70.9c-10.7 0-16.1 13-8.5 20.5l114.9 114.3c4.7 4.7 12.2 4.7 16.9 0l114.9-114.3c7.6-7.6 2.2-20.5-8.5-20.5H300V140c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-64c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12z"></path></svg>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" id="btnRemove">
          <svg width="20px" height="20px" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="times-circle" class="svg-inline--fa fa-times-circle fa-w-16 text-success" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8zm121.6 313.1c4.7 4.7 4.7 12.3 0 17L338 377.6c-4.7 4.7-12.3 4.7-17 0L256 312l-65.1 65.6c-4.7 4.7-12.3 4.7-17 0L134.4 338c-4.7-4.7-4.7-12.3 0-17l65.6-65-65.6-65.1c-4.7-4.7-4.7-12.3 0-17l39.6-39.6c4.7-4.7 12.3-4.7 17 0l65 65.7 65.1-65.6c4.7-4.7 12.3-4.7 17 0l39.6 39.6c4.7 4.7 4.7 12.3 0 17L312 256l65.6 65.1z"></path></svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-7">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button id="consultar" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            VISUALIZAR
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="consultar">
            <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item" name="tela">
              <svg width="15" height="15" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="tv" class="svg-inline--fa fa-tv fa-w-20" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M592 0H48A48 48 0 0 0 0 48v320a48 48 0 0 0 48 48h240v32H112a16 16 0 0 0-16 16v32a16 16 0 0 0 16 16h416a16 16 0 0 0 16-16v-32a16 16 0 0 0-16-16H352v-32h240a48 48 0 0 0 48-48V48a48 48 0 0 0-48-48zm-16 352H64V64h512z"></path></svg>
              Tela</button>           
            <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item" name="excel">
              <svg width="15" height="15" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="file-excel" class="svg-inline--fa fa-file-excel fa-w-12" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M369.9 97.9L286 14C277 5 264.8-.1 252.1-.1H48C21.5 0 0 21.5 0 48v416c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h288c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V131.9c0-12.7-5.1-25-14.1-34zM332.1 128H256V51.9l76.1 76.1zM48 464V48h160v104c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h104v288H48zm212-240h-28.8c-4.4 0-8.4 2.4-10.5 6.3-18 33.1-22.2 42.4-28.6 57.7-13.9-29.1-6.9-17.3-28.6-57.7-2.1-3.9-6.2-6.3-10.6-6.3H124c-9.3 0-15 10-10.4 18l46.3 78-46.3 78c-4.7 8 1.1 18 10.4 18h28.9c4.4 0 8.4-2.4 10.5-6.3 21.7-40 23-45 28.6-57.7 14.9 30.2 5.9 15.9 28.6 57.7 2.1 3.9 6.2 6.3 10.6 6.3H260c9.3 0 15-10 10.4-18L224 320c.7-1.1 30.3-50.5 46.3-78 4.7-8-1.1-18-10.3-18z"></path></svg>
              Excel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item" name="pdf">
              <svg width="15" height="15" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="file-pdf" class="svg-inline--fa fa-file-pdf fa-w-12" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M369.9 97.9L286 14C277 5 264.8-.1 252.1-.1H48C21.5 0 0 21.5 0 48v416c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h288c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V131.9c0-12.7-5.1-25-14.1-34zM332.1 128H256V51.9l76.1 76.1zM48 464V48h160v104c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h104v288H48zm250.2-143.7c-12.2-12-47-8.7-64.4-6.5-17.2-10.5-28.7-25-36.8-46.3 3.9-16.1 10.1-40.6 5.4-56-4.2-26.2-37.8-23.6-42.6-5.9-4.4 16.1-.4 38.5 7 67.1-10 23.9-24.9 56-35.4 74.4-20 10.3-47 26.2-51 46.2-3.3 15.8 26 55.2 76.1-31.2 22.4-7.4 46.8-16.5 68.4-20.1 18.9 10.2 41 17 55.8 17 25.5 0 28-28.2 17.5-38.7zm-198.1 77.8c5.1-13.7 24.5-29.5 30.4-35-19 30.3-30.4 35.7-30.4 35zm81.6-190.6c7.4 0 6.7 32.1 1.8 40.8-4.4-13.9-4.3-40.8-1.8-40.8zm-24.4 136.6c9.7-16.9 18-37 24.7-54.7 8.3 15.1 18.9 27.2 30.1 35.5-20.8 4.3-38.9 13.1-54.8 19.2zm131.6-5s-5 6-37.3-7.8c35.1-2.6 40.9 5.4 37.3 7.8z"></path></svg>
              PDF</button>
          </div>
        </div>
<!--        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="consultar" name="consultar" value="CONSULTAR" /> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
    $('#btnAdd').click(function (e) {
        $('select').moveToList('#Lista1', '#Lista2');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#btnRemove').click(function (e) {
        $('select').removeSelected('#Lista2');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#btnUp').click(function (e) {
        $('select').moveUpDown('#Lista2', true, false);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#btnDown').click(function (e) {
        $('select').moveUpDown('#Lista2', false, true);
        e.preventDefault();
    }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vc exibe o que vc escolhe exibir. 
Se vc fizer uma chamada a uma pagina que responda o HTML inteiro e colocar para exibir o HTML todo, ele vai exibir o HTML todo.
Detalhe melhor seu código. Esse trecho de código (o javascript) que vc colocou não bate com resultado que vc detalhou. "exibi o HTML todo no console" porém o que ta no código é para dar um alert do codigo todo.

Comment: @Fabricio vou postar todo o código, talvez fique mais claro. Mas em resumo o que eu quero é, usar o texto exibido no primeiro `select`A para criar um segundo `select`B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi você está deixando ambos os códigos na mesma página.

Quando você ta fazendo o POST via ajax você está recebendo o código inteiro. Quando você só quer receber o código que contem o seu select.

Você até pode deixar tudo em um .php só, mas tem que fazer validação de que retornar. Exemplo:

Arquivo relatorios.php

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') && (!empty($_POST['tabela'])) {
        //var_dump($_POST);
        @$tabela = $_POST['tabela'];
        $opcoes = "";
        $cabeca = "";
        $campo = array("/idt_embarque/i","/invoice/i","/nr_doc_carga_mast/i","/nr_doc_carga/i","/dt_di/i","/nr_di/i","/qtd_adicoes/i","/historico/i");
        $titulo = array("IDENTIFICACAO","NR INVOICE","NR MASTER","NR HOUSE","DATA D.I.","NR D.I.","NR ADICOES","HISTORICO");

        $arg = array("select"=>"*","tabela"=>"TAB_RELATORIOS","where"=>"where login='{$_SESSION['login']}' and nome='{$tabela}'");
        $obj_rel = $obj_pdo->getConsultaDI($arg);
        if(!empty($obj_rel)){
            $opcoes = explode("|",$obj_rel[0]->OPCOES);
            $tl_rel = count($opcoes)-1;
            print '<div class="form-group col-md-5">';
            print '<label class="control-label" for="Lista2">Itens Rel.</label>';
            print '<select multiple class="form-control" id="Lista2" name="Lista2[]">';
            for($i=0; $tl_rel > $i; $i++){ //inicio do for
                $cabeca = preg_replace($campo, $titulo, $opcoes[$i]);
                if($opcoes[$i] === "cd_processo"){
                    print '<option hidden selected value="cd_processo"></option>';
                }elseif($opcoes[$i] === "dt_recebimento_doc"){
                    print '<option hidden selected value="dt_recebimento_doc"></option>';
                }else{
                    print '<option value="'.$opcoes[$i].'">'.$cabeca.'</option>';
                }
            }// fim do for
            print '</select>';
            print '</div>';
        }
        // Sair para não enviar mais nada.
        exit;
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<title>Relatório de Follow Up Honda</title>
//restante do seu código
```

Normalmente eu deixo em outro arquivo .php. Exemplo: relatorios2.php

Independente de como você fizer essa parte. Você precisa alterar o seu AJAX para quando receber o sucesso da chamada trocar o conteúdo da div com o código retornado. Exemplo:

```
function mostra(lista){
    var x = lista.options[lista.options.selectedIndex];
    var nome = x.text;
    if(lista.value != "0"){
        $("#Lista2").prop("hidden", true);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'relatorios.php',
            cache: false,
            data: { 'tabela': nome },
            success: function(retorno){
                //alert(retorno);
                $("#Lista2").html(retorno);
            }
        });
    }else{
        $("#Lista2").prop("hidden", false);
    }
}
```

Dica: ao invés de deixar o listener com o onclick no select, utilize o onchange.

Dica2: Não deixe o nome como variável de consulta. Utilize o valor que você já popula no value do seu option. Assim você não fica restrito no formato do nome que quer exibir para o usuário. Além de ser muito mais lógico e simples a programação. Pode utilizar por exemplo a chave primaria da sua tabela no value, o que vai deixar mais performático a sua consulta ao banco. Ao invés de consultar por uma string gigante sem um índice, consulta por um inteiro indexado.

Comment: como posso fazer para receber o `value` do meu `select` e colocar o mesmo em uma variável `PHP`? Quero fazer isso na mesma página, sem precisar fazer um refresh.